# Javascript variable from array null value until browser refresh

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies

Hoping someone can shed light on this.  I'm grabbing values from a cookie that is comma separated (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5) setting this to a variable.  Everything is fine until i try to access the variables set from an array which are null until i refresh browser. Any ideas?

```
//Setting ExampleVar Cookie
var ExampleVar = null;
var ExampleVar = readCookie('SomeCookie');
if (ExampleVar == null) {
createCookie('SomeCookie',ValuesVariable,365)//create cookie if null
}

var ExampleVar = null;
var ExampleVar = readCookie('CookieGoesHere');//e.g. 1,2,3,4,5
document.write (ExampleVar);//Prints out 1,2,3,4,5 as it should

var myArr = new Array(); 
var myArr = ExampleVar.split(",");
for(var i=0;i<myArr.length;i++){  
    document.write("Array Index " + i + " = " + myArr[i] + "<br />");//prints null until     browser is refreshed
}  
var Foo = myArr[0];//set to Null until browser is refreshed
var Bar = myArr[1];//set to Null until browser is refreshed
```

Comment: Show how and where you are setting the cookie

Comment: Sorry - i updated this.  It is legacy I changed this to 'ExampleVar'

Comment: Thanks Chris - i added part of cookie to the top.

Answer (score 1):

you are not populating your array.  It should never print anything.

```
var ExampleVar = readCookie('CookieGoesHere');//e.g. 1,2,3,4,5
var myArr = ExampleVar.split(',');
```

should work

Comment: Sorry (edited my code - had an old variable name in there) - I am already doing the code in this way.  So let me know if there are other suggestions.  Many thanks.

Comment: So the answer is this was a scope issue as some of this info was included in a JS file and not in scope. When I relocated the part of the code (that assigns the array) to the main part of the HTML it works as intended.